# What is the view and ViewGroup passed to ArrayAdapter and RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: java, android

Im super confused between what is passed to the methods initially.

In ArrayAdapter getview method, What is the `View` and `ViewGroup` passed

```
 public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
            ....

        }
```

List_item xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:fontFamily="serif"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the ViewGroup passed in RecyclerView adapter here.

```
@Override
    public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Number_list_item is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_number"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        tools:text="#42" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**What does the below line do exacty besides inflating the layout.**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, 
                                 shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
```

When you want to show any view on UI it must have some height and width. In a `inflate` method,

- First parameter is a resource id of a view, which should inflate. In a case of Adapter, it should be item view which is going to be recycled.
- Second parameter is a `ViewGroup`, generally parent view. Parent view must be a `ViewGroup` because ViewGroup contains child views not vice versa. In a case of `ListView` sometimes size(width) of an inflated view not adopted automatically depends on its parent.

> For an example - If a `ListView` have a width `match_parent` then there is a possibility width of your inflated view less than its parent if you skipped this parameter.

- Third parameter is used to decide whether you want to add your inflated view inside parent `ViewGroup`(2nd parameter). In a case of `ListView`, if you make it true then you will get `RunTimeException` (`View` already have a parent), this parameter should be true if you want to add new view inside parent view.

> For an example - If I want to add `View` in my UI only after sudden action, then I will inflate a 'View' and add in a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Hi, is the viewgroup, the parentview defined in xml layout of LISTVIEW or list_item xml.

Comment: Parent of ItemView which you inflated have a direct parent ListView or RecyclerView in your case

Comment: @raxx I would suggest you, write if check that viewGrouo is instanceOf ListView/RecyclerView for testing purpose only

Comment: So for ArrayAdapter, initially when system calls ConverterView will be null and ViewGroup will be the ListView of List_Item (even if ListView is in separate xml) ? And for recyclerAdapter ViewGroup will be the RecycleView ?? right

Comment: @ raxx exactly.